# UWP companion .NET App crashing on some machines

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, dependencies

A UWP app i built hosts a .NETCore companion application "FullTrustProcess", it runs fine on my main machine but crashes on others, it seems I could be missing a .NETCore dependency on various systems, how do I find out what I am missing to ensure they are bundled with the appx?

Comment: Are you building stand - alone or shared framework? The default is shared framework which won't work if the user doesn't have the runtime installed.

Comment: Publish your .NET Core app as self-contained, and then it has no extra dependency on Windows.

Comment: @Lex Li You are correct that the app needs to published as self-contained. However, the packaged .NET core app still needs to declare a VCLIB dependency (it's a bug …), so this kind of package needs to declare two VCLIB dependencies one for the UWP part and one for the "win32" part, i.e. the NET core app. Chances are this is the problem that Sixjac is hitting. Sixjac: can you post the dependency section of your appxmanifest?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT if I understand correctly, the VC++ runtime dependency has been eliminated in .NET Core 2.x, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x#net-core-dependencies

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT sorry for the very late response, my dependencies in the .wapproj as follows:                                                                    
    <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT and in the .csproj appxmanifest:                    
 <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>

Comment: No answers anyone??